# How to implement this type of model inheritance and how to link a table to any other table in django

Tags: django, database, schema

I have the following arrangement of tables:

[image: Arrangement of tables]
**How it works at the moment:**

An Event can be created and may be be extended, based the EventType it is linked to.

If the EventType has additional fields (if has_additional_fields is true) then the Event will be extended by a table called "EventType_TheNameOfTheEventType", however, if the EventType does not have additional fields, then the Event will not be extended by other table.

If the Event is extended, additional input fields will be available.

The table of the row that the "type_data" field of the Event is referencing will be known because of how the tables will be named.

**Example:**

An Event of type "Project" (the EventType name) may have an additional field such as "Group" and will differ from an Event of type "Meeting", which may have additional fields such as "Topic".

An Event of type "Normal" will have no additional fields.

**Question:**

Is this the best way of implementing this kind of inheritance?

I would like an idea of how to create the models for this in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has the [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) framework so you can name concrete events as you wish:

```
class EventType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    has_additional_fields = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)

class Event(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField(null=True)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(EventType)

    def get_real_model(self):
        return self.event_type.content_type.model_class()

    def get_concrete_event(self):
        return self.event_type.content_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.pk)

class ProjectEvent(Event):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MeetingEvent(Event):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class NormalEvent(Event):
    pass
```

Get a list of all events:

```
Event.objects.all()
```

Get a list of projects:

```
ProjectEvent.objects.all()
```

Get the concrete ("unknown") event by id:

```
Event.objects.get(pk=id).get_concrete_event()
```

Get the real model of the event by id:

```
Event.objects.get(pk=id).get_real_model()
```

Get the form to edit concrete event:

```
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory

event = Event.objects.get(pk=id)
EventForm = modelform_factory(event.get_real_model())
form = EventForm(instance=event.get_concrete_event())
```

Get the same form then you know event type:

```
ProjectEventForm = modelform_factory(ProjectEvent)
form = ProjectEventForm(instance=ProjectEvent.objects.get(pk=id))
```

Comment: I'm confused about something. Does the content_type field in the EventType class link to the content type of one of the event types? For instance, does it link to the content type of the ProjectEvent, if the EventType's name is "project"?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. `content_type` field points to `Event` or one of the `Event`'s descendants (`ProjectEvent`, `MeetingEvent` etc),

Comment: Ok, yes, that makes logical sense. But when I create an EventType, how do I link it to a content type?

Comment: `content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ProjectEvent)`

Comment: Ah right. Last thing, when you say 'real model' is it the sort of abstract python object and when you say 'concrete event' is it the event object but filled with data?

Comment: By "real model" I mean the model class (Event or it's descendant). "Concrete event" is the instance of that class (and yes, it is the event object with data).